# 'Object expected' error from IE8 using YouTube API

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, youtube-api

Experiencing problems in IE8 with some javascript used to display YouTube videos using the Data API.

The error I'm getting is 'Object Expected', stemming from the second code line.

```
// <![CDATA[
var baseUrl = 'http://www.youtube.com/';
var swfUrl = constructUrl(baseUrl);

// allowScriptAccess must be set to allow the Javascript from one
// domain to access the swf on the youtube domain
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", bgcolor: "#cccccc" };

// This sets the ID of the DOM object or embed tag to 'myytplayer'.
// You can use this ID to access the swf and call the player's API
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
var flashvars = {};
swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, "ytapiplayer", "220", "125", "9", null,
  flashvars, params, atts);
//]]>
```

Has anyone come across this error, and do you have any tested solutions?

Comment: What's "constructUrl()"?

Answer (score 1):

IE will spit out the "object expected" error on a lot of things, including undefined functions. Most likely within the context of this function, you haven't included the library that defines `constructURL()`.